# Capacitor selection on Kicad

Tags: capacitor, footprint

Can someone assist me in finding the correct footprint for this capacitor?

The footprints on Kicad are:

What does CP_elec_3x5.3 relate to? What does 3 x 5.3 mean?

[image]

And the capsize is here:

[image]

Comment: These are aluminium electrolytic capacitors and if I remember correctly this is the size in mm.
Can we have the part number of your part ?

Comment: Have you examined a few of the footprints? How are they different? What have you done to find a correlation between the name and the actual footprint?

Comment: @Mat 
 https://www.digikey.co.za/en/products/detail/nichicon/UUJ1V471MNQ6MS/3768818

Comment: Ok you can find the footprint on Snapeda here https://www.snapeda.com/parts/UUJ1V471MNQ6MS/Nichicon/view-part/?ref=search&t=UUJ1V471MNQ6MS
It's a Snapeda footprint so that should be a good one, I never had an issue with Snapeda created parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although digikey does hide it, they have links to the KiCAD models on the product page:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I suggest also grabbing the 3D STEP files and loaded them into KiCAD as well.  That way you can check that your eventual board doesn't put components too close or in hard to solder places.

Answer (score 4):

Diameter of 3 mm, height of 5.3mm. But you could also just look at the footprint. If your desired dimensions are not in the library, then you have to draw a footprint yourself.

Comment: I've noticed that the KiCad library strikes out pretty frequently with SMD electrolytic sizes.  Or maybe I'm just designing around weird parts.

Comment: I just recently started with KiCad at V6, but electrolytic caps are not among the footprints I've needed to make (I've used only 4mm, 6.3mm and 8mm diameter parts). I find the selection ok, but - coming from EasyEDA, which has an extremely large library both from the app itself aswell as community content - it is quite a step back. However, KiCad is a strong improvement in many other respects.